# Проблема с bash скриптом и базой данных

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте! Возникли  проблемы с bash скриптом,тестовый прогон дает странные результаты. За одну отработку исполняемого файла в документ с базой заносятся запросы для mysql и количество этих запросов различно что и вызывает ошибку.Подскажите где в коде происходит сбой и как его устранить?

```
    >$sqldir/$numberssql
    >$sqldir/$callssql
             cd $logs

                  for j in `ls`
                      do
                   cd $logs/01
                            for i in `ls`
                                do
    cat $logs/01/$i | tr ',' ' ' | awk '{print "insert into numbers(device_name,device_number) values  ("$58","$9");"}'|sed  '1,2d' | grep -v "\"\"" >> $sqldir/$numberssql
    cat $logs/01/$i | tr ',' ' ' | awk '{if ($56 != 0 && (-z $9)) print "insert into calls(incoming_number, calling_number, call_start, final_call, duration)  values ((Select id_numbers from numbers where device_number ="$9"),"$30", "$48", "$49", "$56");"}'|sed '1,2d' >> $sqldir/$callssql

                   echo $i
                                done
                       done
    mysql -D ….. -uroot –p …. <$sqldir/$numberssql
    echo "end num"
    mysql -D ….. -uroot –p …. <$sqldir/$numberssql
    echo "end call"
```

Comment: У вас есть цикл по `j` но в нем вы почему то переходите всегда в одну и ту же папку, не используя `j` больше нигде. И в одном awk есть `if` а в другом нет, следовательно они дадут разное кол-во записей, если вы об этом конечно писали. А вообще не видя вашей структуры каталогов и содержимого файлов и БД что либо понять невозможно

Comment: @Mike- Спасибо!